# Three.js point lights causing huge FPS drop

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js, game-engine

I would like to know how exactly point light works in Three.js. My issue is quite simple but I did not manage to overcome it no matter what I have tried.

I have a huge 3D scene created in canvas with Three.js, even though it is quite big and you can move across this scene with camera, FPS is still around 60. But if I start adding sources of light, namely point lights (street lamps), at some point FPS drastically drops to the point that my browser stops working (the more sources of light the worse performance). It is nothing new that it is computationaly expensive, but the number of lights is not so big. Let's say 30 sources.

But still I would solve this by just decreasing the view (camera.far) distance so that not all the lights are rendered at the same time which in my opinion should help. As expected, if you decrease the camera far property, you will not be able to see all the lights, but the problem persists. Even if I decrease the view distance to minimum, lets say 200px so I do not see any light, the FPS still stays low. This part I do not quite understand so if anyone can clarify that for me it would be awesome.

Another thing is, that even if I can see all the lights (with big camera distance), if I turn camera the other side, the FPS jumps to normal. I can partially comprehend this behavior but still those lights have to be rendered. Can anyone clarify this little bit more?

And the main question is: how to put all the lights on the scene without such FPS drop? As I have mentioned, I am fine with not seeing them all at the same time, but how to make this work?

Comment: WebGLRenderer, I presume? Try setting `light.visible = false` judiciously as an experiment. Or have a look at the experimental `WebGLDeferredRenderer`: http://threejs.org/examples/webgldeferred_pointlights.html.

Comment: Yes, the way WebGLRenderer works it can't easily handle many lights. Basically, if you have 2 lights it goes 2x slower. I don't know if this will be improved in the future.

Comment: Has there been any change in this situation? I just added a few moving pointlights and its absolutely crushing my fps.